# CSS Buttons with Images, possible to not call an Image?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to start using buttons like this on my site:

```
<button type="submit" class="positive" name="save">
    <img src="images/apply2.png" alt=""/>
    Save
</button>
```

But I'd like to avoid making an image request... Is there a browser save way that I can use a data/image in CSS for the image TAG? Or possible not an image tag there? Is it safe to use a SPAN with a sprite background-image?

Thoughts thanks?

Answer (score 2):

A span sprite would work too, but probably cleaner would just be to set the `background-image` of the `button[name=save]` itself. You'd need to be sure the sprite had enough transparent space for the text next to the button, and the margins, I suppose. You'd also want to style the button appropriately, e.g. its border, so that it doesn't use the ugly browser defaults that come into effect once you give a button a background image.